# How can I make my EditorFor disabled?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC Razor *Create* view and my model contains one or more fields that need to be auto-filled by the system, such as "Timestamp" and "Username". Because these fields are required, they need to be in the form.

Here is an example of what the default code looks like when you allow Visual Studio to scaffold your views from a controller.

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoseUserName, 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoseUserName, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoseUserName, "", 
                  new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This what the code looks like when rendered. It's functional, but the first and third fields are fully editable when it shouldn't be. So the question is how we can have EditorFor fields that feed the correct data into the model when the form is submitted but that the user can't change?

[image: This is what the default Create form looks like]

**Further Explanation**
While there are some reasons you might want to keep those fields hidden from view, there are also valid reasons you would want these fields to be seen by the user, such as in a company intranet with users who expect to see that information. While a datestamp could be autogenerated by SQL Server with a `getdate()` default value, capturing the user's identity under Windows Authentication would need to be done from from the MVC side. The identification of the user is part of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important database features is the ability to have computed properties. If you're mapping your code first classes to tables that contain computed properties, you don't want Entity Framework to try to update those columns. But you do want EF to return those values from the database after you've inserted or updated data. You can use the DatabaseGenerated annotation to flag those properties in your class along with the Computed enum. Other enums are None and Identity.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)] 
     public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Now just have your database generate the time stamp when the record is created. You can also set DataAnnotation to read only like so

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)] 
[Editable(false)]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps
**Update**

```
// Private
private DateTime _createdOn = DateTime.Now;
// Public property
[Display(Name = "Created On")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime CreatedOn
{
            get
            {
                return (_createdOn == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : _createdOn;
            }
            set { _createdOn = value; }
}
```

Or in the View.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommentTime, new { @Value=System.DateTime.Now })
```

Or in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Birth = DateTime.Now
        });
    }
```

If done in the controller and/or model you can use the html attribute of readonly like so.

You could use a custom editor template:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("MyHiddenDate")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and then define ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyHiddenDate.cshtml:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.Hidden("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

and finally in your view use the EditorFor helper:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
```

This will render the custom editor template for the Date property of the view model and consequently render the hidden field with a value using the desired format.

**UPDATE**

The EditorFor html helper does not have overloads that take HTML attributes. In this case, you need to use something more specific like TextBoxFor:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateCreated , new 
        { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
```

You can still use EditorFor, but you will need to have a TextBoxFor in a custom EditorTemplate:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [UIHint("DateCreated ")]
    public string DateCreated { ;get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder, create a file DateCreated .cshtml. In that file, put this:

```
@model string
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new {  @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: Good to know. I'm new to MVC and am still learning.  In any case, I did Database First. The database already exists. While SQL Server can have a getdate() as a default datetime value, the user identity is the windows user identity and would not be appropriate to have SQL Server try to figure out.

Comment: I tried displayfor before I posted, but when I clicked the submit button, the model wouldn't accept it, which was why I went back to editorfor. I can use the hidden option for different situations, but for this instance, I want the user to see the values so they can see if either value is incorrect. Basically, I want the values to be seen but not editable and have the same format as the editable controls. I tried `[Editable(false)]`, but it had no effect on the control.

Comment: Set the Date in the controller. or the model. and don't show the field at all.

Comment: In this case, I need to show the date and the user's windows identity.

Comment: Then you must set the date in the model or controller and use the HTML Attribute TextBox is the key here "@Html.TextBox("DateCreated ",new { @readonly="readonly" })", or try and set the model to this    "public DateTime Date {get; private set;}"

Comment: You can also give the textbox the same style as the editfor box. Just add the class to the HTML. as the EditFor template overwrites your Attributes

Comment: The EditorFor html helper does not have overloads that take HTML attributes. In this case, you need to use something more specific like TextBoxFor: or use a custom editor template as listed above

Comment: Thank you @Rich Bailo.  I'm finally seeing how I needed a paradigm shift. Since you first presented a usable model-centered approach, I'll accept yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I posted this answer, it was based on what I was able to find so far. I have learned that this is a case of "Beware what you wish for." The other answers provided point out correctly that following the approach shown below is not a good practice and has at least one false premise, as explained in the conversation thread.

**This is useful only as an explanation of what NOT to do. The answer I accepted shows the approach I adopted.**

The answer is amazingly simple and elegant. Tt just takes an extra phrase: `@readonly="readonly"`.

In better context, the original example was:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoseUserName, 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoseUserName, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoseUserName, "", 
                  new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

All you do is add`@readonly="readonly"`to the EditorFor htmlAttributes, like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoseUserName, 
     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="readonly" } })
```

Problem solved.

[image: This is the EditorFor with a <code>@readonly="readonly" added to the htmlAttributes</code>]

Comment: What is this not a good solution - because (1) your just sending extra information to the view and then posting it back again unchanged (degrades performance) (2) a malicious user can easily override the values and you will be none the wiser. How should it be done - Create a view model containing only those properties you need. If your want to display `UserName` and `DateStamp` then just use `@Html.DisplayFor()` otherwise omit them from the view model. When you post, get the data model from the repository and update its properties based on the view model properties and then save the data model

Comment: You make some good points. I haven't learned how to create a repository yet, so that's something I'll look into. You describe something that could work for me. The only remaining issue is that I have been unable to make the rendered `DisplayFor` look the same as the `EditorFor`. But that's a different thread. In any case, I have more research to do. Thank you.

Comment: That's just a matter of using css to style it. Put `@Html.DisplayFor()` inside a (say) `<div class="readonly">` then use css to set the borders, padding etc (inspect the css of an dummy disabled textbox to see all the values to set)

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke. I'm finally seeing how I needed a paradigm shift.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoseUserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoseUserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoseUserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Add `disabled = "disabled"`, `@readonly = "readonly"` along with `@class = "form-control"`, so you have:

```js
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoseUserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"} })
```